# Using bluetooth mouse and keyboard on windows remote desktop android app?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, android

I want to have access to a bluetooth keyboard and a bluetooth mouse connected to my android phone when using windows remote desktop to my pc. Would this work? Would the bluetooth devices need to be compatible with android, windows, or both?

Comment: You would have to "pair" your BT keyboard and your BT mouse with each - Windows RDP and Android. But you have to decide which one if they are at the same location. I haven't practical experience, so others may add useful information on how to to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works.
I've recently bought an samsung galaxy tab s6 and i use remote desktop to connect to my windows pc at home.
I'm using a bluetooth mouse and keyboard right now as I am typing this to you. I have a rapoo bluetooth mouse and a trust mini keyboard, also using bluetooth.

Comment: you can even use the keyboard and mouse directly on the android os. the mouse cursor will pop up and you can type with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Bluetooth mouse/keyboard combinations (Google for one you like). Then it needs only be compatible with your Android device as that will being controlling your Windows machine via a remote connection.

Comment: This seems logical, but I still fear that somehow the remote desktop software will break this. It would be really cool if someone could confirm that this works.

Answer (score 0):

Convert any laptop to touchscreen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxE_1NE4xEI Android App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.touchscreen.lite

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187791)